# Bash Can not get IF to work like I want to

Tags: bash, types, boolean

I need to understand bash if expressions. Sure, I've used Google. I know that it goes something like this:

```
if [ expr operator expr ]
then
doSomeThing
fi
```

However, I understand that Bash doesn't have a boolean data type. I want to check if the file passed as an argument ($1) exists. The way I would do this straight of my mind:

```
if [ -e $1 = true ] 
then 
echo "File exists."
fḯ
```

Or maybe like:

```
if [ -e $1 ] #Assuming that this is true only if file in $1 exists.
```

None of these work, and I'm not sure what [ ] means. -e $1 seems like a smart choice, but it is always true? There are different operators for strings and integers. And I can't use parenthesis to group together expressions. This is so confusing.

Anyone got a few hints? The IF in bash does not work like if I've tried in any other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ ... ]

means that the program `/usr/bin/test` gets executed with `...` as the arguments and its return value is checked (`0` means `true` and `x != 0` means `false` (yes, `0` really means `true` here because `0` is the `OK` exit code in UNIX)). So

```
if [ -e $1 ]; then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

is correct. It's the same as

```
if test -e $1; then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

The sole problem is that `$1` could contain spaces. If so `/usr/bin/test` gets confused, since it gets 3 or more arguments. The first one (`-e`) is a unary operator (wants one argument). Since you gave it 2 or more (one `/usr/bin/test` argument is the `-e` itself), it complains like that:

```
...: binary operator expected
```

So, simply use

```
if [ -e "$1" ];then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

That will even work if `$1` contains spaces. Another possibility is to use

```
if [[ -e $1 ]]; then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

That will do the same but it gets evaluated by bash itself and no `/usr/bin/test` program gets forked.

Compounds are as usual but `-a` means `and` and `-o` means `or`. So

```
if [ -e /etc/fstab -a -e "$1" ]; then
   echo "ok"
fi
```

will echo ok if `/etc/fstab` and the file given as first command line argument exist.

Comment: What does it do when add "" around $1 => "$1"?

Comment: It will make exactly ONE argument for /usr/bin/test, no matter how many spaces.

Comment: Except that `[` and `test` are also Bash builtins and as such are executed with higher precedence than `/usr/bin/{[,test}`

Answer (score 3):

As other have mentioned, `[` is actually the `test` command, so its arguments get parsed according to standard argument-parsing rule, and this forces some rather inconvenient and confusing syntax.  For example, you can use parentheses, `<`, and `>` in test commands, but you'd better escape them or else the shell will take them to mean something unfortunate.

There's a much better solution: the [conditional expression](http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression), which looks a lot like the old-school test command, but with `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` around the expression.  Because this isn't parsed as a command, it has a much more natural syntax, and also has some more powerful features:

```
if [[ -e $1 && ! -d $1 ]]; then  # if $1 exists but isn't a directory...
    # note that quotes are not needed, since $1 will not undergo word splitting
[[ $string == done ]] # string comparison
[[ $string == a* ]] # glob-style pattern matching: does $string start with "a"?
[[ $string == "*"* ]] # partial glob: does $string start with "*"?
[[ $string =~ ^[[:upper:]] ]] # regex matching: does $string start with an upper-case letter?
[[ $string < g ]] # string comparison: is $string alphabetically before "g"
[[ $num -lt 5 ]] # numeric comparison: is $num numerically less than 5
```

Answer (score 0):

the [ ] is shorthand for bash test command 
http://ss64.com/bash/test.html

if operation in bash checks if return code of the command use for testing is 0.

You can check the return status of any command with:
`echo $?`

For example try this:

```
test -e myfile.txt
echo $?
[ -e myfile.txt ] 
echo ?$
```

Answer (score 0):

1. see `man test`
2. this should work:

   ```
   function foo() {
     if [ -e "$1" ] ; then
       echo "$1 exists"
     fi
   }
   ```
3. There several ways to write a compound expressions:
   and:

   ```
   [ expr1 -a expr2 ]
   ```

   or:

   ```
   [ expr1 -o expr2 ]
   ```

   You can also use the `[[ expr && expr || expr ]]` syntax